# R ggplot2 rmd returning an empty html

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr, ggplotly

Based on the code and data below, the `rmd` knitted fine initially with the code and output (default option), but then I just changed the chunk option to `show output only`. And, since then I am getting an empty `html`. I tried reverting back to default, I even cleared the environment and restarted `RStudio`, but it does not fix it.

What could be causing the issue?

Code + data:

````
---
title: "Gantt Chart"
author: "Ed"
date: "2022-08-12"
output: html_document
editor_options: 
  chunk_output_type: console
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(include = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
```


```{r Gantt Chart, echo=FALSE}

df = data.frame(task=c("Explore Ideas", "Finalize Idea", "Make Plots with\n geom_line", "Make Plots with\n Plan Package", "Add Writeups", "Refine Plots", "Review Tutorial", "Submit Tutorial", "Get Feedback\n and Update"), 
                 start=c("2019-10-15", "2019-10-18", "2019-10-19", "2019-10-22", "2019-10-24", "2019-10-25", "2019-10-26", "2019-10-27", "2019-10-28"),
                 end=c("2019-10-18", "2019-10-19", "2019-10-24", "2019-10-26", "2019-10-27", "2019-10-27", "2019-10-28", "2019-10-28", "2019-10-31"), 
                 owner=c("Harish", "Phani", "Harish", "Phani", "Phani", "Harish", "Phani", "Harish", "Phani"))

head(df)

df = df %>% 
  mutate(start = as.Date(start), end = as.Date(end))

df_tidy = df %>% 
  gather(key=date_type, value=date, -task, -owner)

gantt_plot = ggplot() +
  geom_line(data=df_tidy, mapping=aes(x=fct_rev(fct_inorder(task)), y=date, color=owner), size=10) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=as.Date("2019-10-27"), colour="black", linetype="dashed") +
  coord_flip() +
  scale_y_date(date_breaks = "1 day") +
  labs(title="Community Contribution Gantt Chart",
       x = "Task",
       y = "Date",
       colour = "Owner") +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90),
        panel.grid.minor = element_line(colour="white", size=0.5),
        legend.position="right",
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

ggplotly(gantt_plot)

```
````

Comment: This looks like `echo=FALSE` gets overwritten by `include=FALSE`, if you set your chunk options like this `knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE )` it should work. Have a look here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-3.html

Comment: @Julian, so I should remove `include=FALSE`?

Comment: Yes, I would change the default to `echo = FALSE`.